# Grafana-LogQL: HowTo extract labels from key-value objects in json array

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, grafana, grafana-loki

I am working with ASP.NET 5.0 json logger and logging scopes. I want to populate the scope key-values as labels.
The json produced is of the following format (excerpt):

```
{
"LogLevel": "Information",
"Scopes": [
    {
        "Message": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\u00602[System.String,System.Object]",
        "MsgId": "c08e834e8edb4287ab8abf0b5510bb53"
    },
    {
        "Message": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\u00602[System.String,System.Object]",
        "EventId": "03ec8be0-9975-482e-95b9-2ba6185a4ed4",
        "EventName": "someEvent",
        "EntityKeyValue": "someNonTechId"
    }
]
}
```

The only way I found was to do

```
| json MsgId="Scopes[0].MsgId", EventName="Scopes[1].EventName" etc. ...
```

Problem is that:

- not all scopes are present at all times
- so also the indices could change...

Is there any solution for that?

BTW we operate on a managed cluster, so custom plugins won't work...

Comment: It's not possible, sadly. You'll need use fragile regexp commands to extract fields from the log line as though it were a plain string.